# IIS hosted WCF service is not able to start a process

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, process

I have a WCF service on a server,when I send a request from client application, the service will run a process to communicate with network nodes,this process is critical in my service and if it doesn't run the entire service is useless. the problem is this process never runs :( 
I have been reading solutions for about two days but none of them helped me , I have give the service administrator privileges and check if the .exe file path is  correct here is my code any help would be appreciate.

```
  try
        {
            myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myprocess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myprocess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = myprocessPathAndName; 
            myprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = 
            Path.GetDirectoryName(myprocessPathAndName);
            myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = ConfigName;
            myprocess.Start();
            Log("myprocess Runnig " , sw);
            Log(myprocessPathAndName, sw);
            Log(myprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory, sw);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("Failed to run myprocess : " + e.Message, sw);
        }
```

here is the log

```
7/26/2017 4:05:15 AM : myprocessRunnig 
7/26/2017 4:05:15 AM : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Station\COM\Dn\myprocess.exe
7/26/2017 4:05:15 AM : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Station\COM\Dn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

Check the return value of your `myprocess.Start()` method call. If the process has started successfully, it would return `true`. Log the return value.

[Process.Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start)

Second: (you may be already doing this)

After the process has started, you should have to have a wait call for the process to run and complete.

[Process.WaitForExit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7#System_Diagnostics_Process_WaitForExit)

Third:

How do you determine that the process has not started ? Are you able to check the process in Task Manager ? It is possible that the process is starting and failing. Is there any log created by your process ? Have you checked the event log ?

Fourth:

Does your process have any UI component ? Do note that when running as a Service (in Windows Vista and later), the service cannot show a UI. It would just hang.

Fifth:

Are you able to manually run your process with the same user ID as your Service ? You can use `RunAs` or `PsExec` to run your process under the appropriate user ID.

Sixth:

You can redirect the standard error as well and read from it to see whether your process has written any exception

e.g.,

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

string errResult = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

You can log the result and check it.

Seventh:

You should also log the exit code of your process

```
        process.WaitForExit();

        var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Dear Subbu, actually your Sixth suggestion help me to figure out the cause of this problem I've added  myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; and based on returned value I've found there was a missing config file for my process to start ! Thanks a lot